# Why Ajax callback method not being fired in below code?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Issue: Ajax callback method (get) is not being called.

```
$("input[id*='chkSelect']:checked").each(function (i, v) {

    $.get("AjaxCallHandler.aspx?tc_id=" + tc_id, function (response) {                    
        if (response != null && response != '') {
                //update some labels with the return type
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Server Side:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var str = Request.QueryString["tc_id"] != null ? Request.QueryString["tc_id"] as string : string.Empty;
    int tc_id;
    if (int.TryParse(str, out tc_id))
    {   
        string response = string.Empty;

        if (tc_id %2 == 0)
        {
            response = "sessionId1,Success";
        }
        else
        {
            response = "sessionId2,Failure";
        }

        Response.Clear();            //clears the existing HTML
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";  //change content type
        Response.Write(response);
        Response.End();             //end
    }
}
```

**P.S.** The code worked perfectly fine until I applied different master page to the page. I tried different overload of get method to inspect error, which didn't help either.

```
function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {                    
        if (response != null && response != '') {
                //update some labels with the return type
            }
        }
    }
```

As suggested by Kevin, I tried adding failHandler in **$.get**

```
$.get("AjaxCallHandler.aspx?tc_id=" + tc_id, 
    function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {                    
        if (response != null && response != '') {
                //update some labels with the return type
            }
        }
    }).fail(failHandler);

    function failHandler(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    };
```

Here is the output
**textStatus: parsererror
jqXHR: SyntaxError**

All I have returned from server is `"sessionId1,Success"` can't figure out whats wrong ?

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab?

Comment: Most likely your selector no longer selects the appropriate elements, but without html we can't be sure.

Comment: @KevinB, I have put break-point in chrome debugger at callback method. That is not being hit. So we can rule-out selector mismatch possibility..

Comment: How does that rule out selector mismatch possibility? it's not hitting the breakpoint in the success, which is either caused by the error callback happening, or by the ajax method not being executed at all, which could be due to a selector issue. Place the breakpoint on `$.get` instead. If you hit that, then add an error handler to your `$.get` request (`$.get(...).fail(handler)`) and inspect all three arguments.

Comment: @SLaks @KevinB `sessionId1,Success` I see response coming back, with 200 OK as Http status code

Comment: Ok, so 200 OK should be calling your success callback. Was that a typo in your previous comment, that it IS hitting the callback method?

Comment: Ok. In that case you should console.log(response) to see exactly what is being returned. That if statement is pretty basic, so it should be entering it without issue if the response isn't empty.

Comment: @KevinB Is there a  problem in calling ajax in loop in my scenario ?

Comment: The loop shouldn't cause a problem, other than possibly causing a performance hit due to sending off many ajax requests at once. Functionally though it should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36271/discussion-between-autrevo-and-kevin-b)

Comment: have you tried Response.Flush() before Response.End()